# Why does Pinker classify these words as prepositions in *The Sense of Style*?

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

In his recent book, *The Sense of Style*, Steven Pinker explains permissible uses of commas and writes this sentence

> And when the writer pinpoints the coherence relation he has in mind with an explicit connective such as a coordinator (*and*, *or*, *but, *yet*, *so*, *nor*) or a preposition (*although*, *except*, *if*, *before*, *after*, *because*, *for*), a comma is fine …

(p. 292)

I understand *before* and *after* can be prepositions. However, I can't find a reference that *because* is a preposition. The OED lists senses as an adverb, a conjunction, and a noun. Why has Pinker said that these are *prepositions*? Pinker is a serious linguist, so I don't regard even the OED's entry as an absolute refutation, but he seems to be on his own here.

Comment: I think you really mean *Pinker is a "serious linguist"*.

Comment: The usual position is that they're subordinators (in the senses I assume you mean), as many sources  (eg [Roane State Community College](http://www.roanestate.edu/owl/commas.html)) state.

Comment: I think the basic idea is from Otto Jespersen -- the things called subordinate conjunctions in traditional grammar are really just prepositions that are peculiar in taking sentence complements rather than the familiar nominal complements.  I don't recall Jespersen's reasoning.  You might find a specific reference in McCawley's **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.

Comment: @Greg Lee I rarely find myself in the position of feeling I must advocate a traditional grammar stance. Rarely, but not never.

Comment: This is a good example of why questions about part of speech should be off limits. These words are subordinators with various properties; Pinker and CGEL call them "prepositions". I can live with that, and I may even use it someday. Arguments about what they "really" are are pointless, though if all the OQ wants is a reference, they can use CGEL.

Comment: Since I didn't say what Jespersen's argument was, I can't figure out how John knows it's pointless.  I don't think investigating the syntactic properties of the various categories is a pointless activity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On page 310 of *The Sense of Style* Pinker states:

> The terminology and analyses in this book are based on *The Cambridge
>   Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002).

On page 1011 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston introduces the lengthy analysis that leads him to designating as *prepositions* what in traditional grammar would be called *conjunctions*, among them *although, while, after* and *because*:

> The analysis of content clauses presented in this chapter differs in
>   significant ways from that found in traditional grammar.

Co-author Pullum has written [an entry for Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494) in which he explains the rationale for regarding *because* as a preposition. It includes the following extract:

> So what should we say about *because*? Contrary to all the dictionaries,
>   it is a preposition. As its complement (the phrase that follows it to
>   complete the PP) it may take either a clause (as in the PP *because he
>   holds ridiculous beliefs*) or a PP with *of* as its head (as in the PP
>   *because of our public universities*). Some prepositions can occur with
>   no complement (as in *We went in*), some require an NP (as *of* does) some
>   require a clause (as *although* does), and some require a PP (like *out*
>   in those uses that do not involve exiting from delimited regions of
>   space: notice that *They did it out of ignorance* is grammatical but
>   *They did it out ignorance* is not).

So, in summary, Pinker is following the CGEL in listing *although, except, if, before, after, because, for* as prepositions.

Comment: The French wisely have _parce que_ for the subordinator _because_, and _à cause de_ for the [multi-word preposition](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000360.htm) _because of_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. And German has _weil/da_ for the subordinator _because_ and _wegen_ for the preposition _because of_. As an aside, I find the CGEL analysis interesting and fairly persuasive, but until the rest of the linguistic world (dictionaries and pedagogic grammars, for example) catch up - if they ever do - then we are going to have questions such as the one above.

Comment: There are strong arguments against the lumping of say _around_ in _We arrived at the edge of the lake and walked around_ and _because_ in _He went to Paris because he believed she was there_ in the preposition class. I find the CGEL analysis interesting but unpersuasive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice to see one of your less dogmatic and aggressive comments regarding this issue.

Comment: @Araucaria Man Nice to be able to consider that's what's required.